# Program to check out various code repositories

Tags: windows-7, version-control

I frequently find myself needing to download source code or binaries from various repositories all over from different version control mechanisms (SVN repos, hg and git, etc).

Does there exist a program for Windows that functions as a "read-only" type of application for different source control repositories? One where I could open it and download code from a SVN repository, then something from github, so on and so forth?

It doesn't need to have the ability to commit or diff or any fancy features -- just downloading.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of one truly universal system, except for **[Amp](http://amp.carboni.ca/)**, but it is still a work in progress.